# What am I doing wrong with the Sutherland Hodgman algorithm?

Tags: c++, math, polygon, clipping

Apologies for the wall of code below... but I'm not 100% sure of where the exact issue is. I'm using the Sutherland Hodgman clipping algorithm to find the contact points in my collision detection system (physics engine for my undergrad thesis). The vertices it returns are MOSTLY correct however I often get a lot of false positives on the InsideEdge function or incorrect intersections. If anyone can help I'd be so grateful! I have tried with many different input vertices and the result varies, however the X-axis does seem to be the most consistently correct.

Example IO with visual:

Input: clipping vertices [ (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, -2.0), (-2.0, -2.0), (-2.0, 2.0) ], poly vertices [ (2.5, 3.0), (2.5, 1.0), (0.5, 1.0), (0.5, 3.0) ]

Output: (2.0, 1.0), (0.5, 1.0), (0.5, 3.0 (*wrong*))

[image: img]

```
 bool SAT::InsideEdge(double px, double py, double edgeMaxX, double edgeMaxY, double edgeMinX, double edgeMinY) 
    {
        double one = (edgeMaxX - edgeMinX) * (py - edgeMinY);
        double two = (edgeMaxY - edgeMinY) * (px - edgeMinX);
        return (one - two) < 0; 
    }

void SAT::SutherlandHodgman(std::vector<Vector3>& _clipped, const Vector3& normal, const Vector3* polyVertices, const Vector3* clippingVertices)
{
    const unsigned maxPoints = 16;
    Vector3 newPoints[maxPoints];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        newPoints[i] = polyVertices[i];
    }
    unsigned newSize = 0;

    for (unsigned edge = 0; edge < numEdges; edge++) //for each clipping edge
    {
        //NOTE: axes is a 2D array to define which two axes to consider out of x, y, z
        Vector3 edgeMin = clippingVertices[edge];
        Vector3 edgeMax = clippingVertices[(edge + 1) % numEdges];

        for (unsigned v = 0; v < numVertices; v++) //for each input vertex
        {
            Vector3 v1 = newPoints[v];
            Vector3 v2 = newPoints[(v + 1) % numVertices];

            bool insideEdge1 = InsideEdge(v1[axes[0]], v1[axes[1]], edgeMax[axes[0]], edgeMax[axes[1]], edgeMin[axes[0]], edgeMin[axes[1]]);
            bool insideEdge2 = InsideEdge(v2[axes[0]], v2[axes[1]], edgeMax[axes[0]], edgeMax[axes[1]], edgeMin[axes[0]], edgeMin[axes[1]]);

            if (insideEdge1 && insideEdge2)
            {
                newPoints[newSize] = v2;
                newSize++;
            }
            else if (!insideEdge1 && insideEdge2)
            {
                newPoints[newSize] = CalculateIntersection(v1, v2, axes, edgeMin, edgeMax);
                newSize++;
                newPoints[newSize] = v2;
                newSize++;
            }
            else if (insideEdge1 && !insideEdge2)
            {
                newPoints[newSize] = CalculateIntersection(v1, v2, axes, edgeMin, edgeMax);
                newSize++;
            }
        }
        numVertices = newSize;
        if (numVertices >= maxPoints)
            break;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        //Removes duplicates before adding to the final list
        VerifyVertex(_clipped, newPoints[i]);
    }
}
```

And the calculate intersection code...

```
//x intersect
    double num = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4);
    double den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);
    double X = num / den;

    //y intersect
    num = (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4);
    den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);
    double Y = num / den;

    Vector3 intersection;
    intersection[axes[0]] = X;
    intersection[axes[1]] = Y;

    //Get the value of the remaining axis
    double percAcrossLine = 1;
    if (x2 != 0)
        percAcrossLine = (x1 + X) / x2;
    else if (y2 != 0)
        percAcrossLine = (y1 + Y) / y2;

    unsigned i = 0;
    if (axes[0] == 0)
    {
        if (axes[1] == 1)
            i = 2;
        else if (axes[1] == 2)
            i = 1;
    }

    intersection[i] = v1[i] + (v2[i] - v1[i]) * percAcrossLine;

    return intersection;
```

Comment: 1) Please post a [mcve].  2) What debugging have you done on your code?  3) Note that `double` and floating-point in general may not give you exact results.  Computer math isn't exactly the same as what you do in your math book.

Comment: When clipping a convex polygon to a convex 'view' polygon, the conservative assertion is that each 'line' of the clipping polygon can add one vertex to the convex polygon being clipped. Imagine a square as a 'viewport', and rotate the square by 45 degrees as an example convex polygon. You end up with 8 vertices. I think this is a reasonable code snippet, and what worries me is the complexity of changing the vertex count. This is a case where I would not use `std::vector` management - simply starting with (4) extra vertices of storage, and manually track the running vertex count.

Comment: If you really need to, unroll your clipping code so that each 'code block' clips to an edge. When that is working, *then* you can start folding common code while being able to test it against 'known' working implementation.